# Since the Standard C committee did not standardize a simple replacement for gets(), what should it be?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, glibc, libc

The `gets` function was first deprecated in C99 and finally removed in C11.  Yet there is no direct replacement for it in the C library.

`fgets()` is not a drop-in replacement because it does not strip the final `'\n'`, which may be absent at the end of file.  Many programmers get it wrong too.

There is a one-liner to remove the linefeed: `buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';`, but it is non-trivial and often calls for an explanation.  It may be inefficient as well.

This is counter-productive.  Many beginners still use `gets()` because their teachers are lame or their tutorials obsolete.

Microsoft proposed `gets_s()` and many related functions, but it does not silently truncate overlong lines, the behavior on this *constraint violation* is not exactly simple.

Both BSD and the GNU libc have `getline`, standardized in POSIX, that allocates or reallocates a buffer via `realloc`...

What is the best way to teach beginners about this mess?

Comment: POSIX `getline` is even more non-trivial than `fgets` .  `scanf` with `%[` is another option, although it has its own pitfalls.    `fgets` doesn't seem too bad to me, it has the advantage of being able to tell whether or not the line exceeded the buffer.

Comment: Use `fgets` and `fputs`, forbid `gets` and (for symmetry) `puts`, and just deal with `'\n'` and allocations?

Comment: `puts` is perfectly fine

Comment: @M.M Use `puts` and people will ask "but what's so bad about `gets` then?" Keep in mind that this question is *didactic* in nature, not *technical*.

Comment: That'd be the perfect opportunity to explain what is actually so bad about `gets` . Beginner C education has to include discussion of buffer overflows and the importance of not doing it.

Comment: @M.M: `scanf` is definitely not a decent replacement for `gets()`.  The size limitation argument is off by one and must be specified explicitly in the format string, inelegance to its max!  `scanf_s` is slightly better but unsupported in BSD and Linux, like `gets_s`...

Comment: The only way this isn't "primarily opinion-based" is if someone from the committee happens by and can quote part of a discussion from the minutes of a meeting or a thread.

Comment: OK, I believe committee members sometimes do read stackoverflow, and if they don't, evidence may be available as to why they did not provide a direct replacement or a recommended alternative.  I'm also asking how to best teach beginners about this.

Comment: The best replacement for gets() is: `assert(1==0);` next question, please!

Comment: I saw `strtok(buf, "\n")` to remove the newline from `fgets`

Comment: @bolov: not a very good idea since `strtok()` is not reentrant. using `strcspn()` is a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

The nature of the question is such that there's going to be speculations and opinions. But we could find some information from the C99 rationale and C11 standard.

The [C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf), when `gets()` was deprecated, states the following reason for the deprecating it:

> Because gets does not check for buffer overrun, it is generally unsafe
>   to use when its input is not under the programmer’s control. This has
>   caused some to question whether it should appear in the Standard at
>   all. The Committee decided that gets was useful and convenient in
>   those special circumstances when the programmer does have adequate
>   control over the input, and as longstanding existing practice, it
>   needed a standard specification. In general, however, the preferred
>   function is fgets (see §7.19.7.2).

I don't think `gets_s()` can be considered as an alternative either. Because `gets_s()` is an optional interface. C11 actually recommends `fgets()` over `gets_s()`:

***§K.3.5.4.1*, C11 draft**

> The fgets function allows properly-written programs to safely process
>   input lines too long to store in the result array. In general this
>   requires that callers of fgets pay attention to the presence or
>   absence of a new-line character in the result array. Consider using
>   fgets (along with any needed processing based on new-line characters)
>   instead of gets_s.

So that leaves us with `fgets()` as the only real replacement for `gets()` in ISO C. `fgets()` is equivalent to `gets()` except it would read in the newline if there's buffer space. So is it worth introducing a new interface that has a minor improvement over a longstanding and widely used (`fgets()`) one? IMO, no.

Besides, a lot of real world applications are not restricted to ISO C alone. So there's an opportunity to use extensions and POSIX `getline()` etc as a replacement.

If it becomes necessary to find write a solution within ISO C, then it's quite easy to write a wrapper around `fgets()` anyway such as `my_fgets()` that would remove the newline, if present.

Of course, teaching `fgets()` to newcomers involves explaining about the potential newline issue. But IMO, it's not that hard to understand and someone intending to do learn C should be able to grasp it quickly. It (finding the last character and replace it if it's character "X") could even be considered as a good exercise for a beginner.

So in light of the above stated reasons, I would say there's no overwhelming necessity for a new function in ISO C as a true replacement for `gets()`.

Answer (score 4):

This question largely calls for speculation short of a citation from committee minutes or something, but as a general principle, the committee (WG14) generally avoids inventing new interfaces and prefers to document and make rigorous existing practice (things like `snprintf`, `long long`, the `inttypes.h` types, etc.) and sometimes adopt from other standards/interface definitions outside of C (e.g. complex math from IEEE floating point, atomic model from C++, etc.). `gets` has no such replacement to adopt, probably because `fgets` is generally considered superior (it's non-lossy when the file ends without a newline). If you really want a direct replacement, something like this works:

```
char buf[100];
scanf("%99[^\n]%*1[\n]", buf);
```

Of course it's klunky to use, especially when the buffer size is variable.

Comment: *the committee (WG14) generally avoids inventing new interfaces* are you kidding?  They invented a slew of multicharacter interfaces of dubious value.

Comment: @chqrlie: There are exceptions, but they're the exception rather than the norm. I'm not entirely clear on what particular example you're talking about. Maybe `uchar.h`?

Comment: This code fails for an empty line (i.e. bare `'\n'` on stream): `%[` is a *matching failure* if no characters are matched, so it will not proceed to the next specifier.

Comment: Indeed, it does seem to fail on a blank line. Any ideas for fixing it? Surely you can just catch the matching failure then `getchar` but it's no longer a single call. Vs `fgets` it avoids a second `O(n)` scan of the string, though.

Comment: @M.M: good catch! as suspected, `scanf` is not a decent replacement.

Comment: Yeah, `scanf("%99[^\n], buf); scanf("%*1[\n]");`

Comment: @M.M: In that case you also need a separate operation to null-terminate the (unwritten) `buf`.

Comment: @R..: `uchar.h`, but also `wchar.h`, `wctype.h`... allowing `wchar_t` to be 16 bit, leading to unsurmountable shortcomings for real internationalization work, and then reversing this with `char32`, but keeping `char16` too... What a mess!

Comment: @M.M: how do you test for end of file then, `feof(stdin)`? (just teasing)

Comment: @chqrlie Worth pointing out that `wchar_t` can be 16 bit because Unicode was supposed to be 16 bit.

Comment: @immibis: Unicode 1.0 was indeed published in 1991 and it soon became obvious that 16 bits would not suffice.  UTF-8 was devised in 1993, but it took another 3 years for Unicode 2.0 to go beyond 16 bits, with the infamous surrogate scheme and the silly 0x10FFFF upper limit, precluding a nice round 20 bit range.  We cannot change the past, but these choices still plague the C language and many others 20 years down the road.

Comment: @chqrlie: `wchar_t` is only permitted to be 16-bit if the implementation only supports UCS-2 or smaller. You cannot support all of unicode with 16-bit `wchar_t`.

Comment: @R..: Alas, platforms such as Microsoft Windows define `wchar_t` as 16 bits and use surrogate pairs for the non BMP code-points.

Comment: @chqrlie: That doesn't actually work. `mbrtowc` can only produce one `wchar_t`, and `wcrtomb` can only process one. The `uchar16_t` functions lift this API limitation so UTF-16 can actually be supported for them, but Windows is just buggy and non-BMP codepoints simply do not work with the C mb/wc API. (Of course they expect you to ignore the standard API and use WinAPI functions instead...)

Comment: @R..: that's the sad truth.  The whole multibyte and wide character support specified in the standard seems too complex to use correctly for most programmers.  Even the basic `<ctype.h>` functions such as `isalpha()` are misused most of the time.  Conversely, proper support of locale specific oddities usually requires special casing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, any replacement would need to pass the `size`as well as the `char *` destination necessitating code changes that were significantly dependent on a case by case basis.  A one-size-fits all was not deemed possible as the `size` is often lost/not passed by the time code gets to `gets()`.  Given the we had a 12 year warning (C99 to C11), suspect the committee felt the problem would be gone by 2011.

Ha!

The Standard C committee should have made a replacement that also passed in the size of the destination.  Like the following.  (this likely has a name collision issue)

```
char *gets_replacement(char *s, size_t size);
```

---

I attempted a `fgets()` based replacement that takes advantage of VLA  (optional in C11)

```
char *my_gets(char *dest, size_t size) {
  // +2 one for \n and 1 to detect overrun
  char buf[size + 2];

  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    // improve error handling - see below comment
    if (size > 0) {
      *buf = '\0';
    }
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t len = strlen(buf);
  if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '\n') {
    buf[--len] = '\0';
  }

  // If input would have overrun the original gets()
  if (len >= size) {
    // or call error handler
    if (size > 0) {
      *buf = '\0';
    }
    return NULL;  
  }
  return memcpy(dest, buf, len + 1);
}
```

Comment: *Given the we had a 12 year warning (C99 to C11), suspect the committee felt the problem would be gone by 2011.*  From our experience here on stackoverflow, the problems is very sticky.  Beginners still use `gets`.

Comment: Your proposed implementation has the same shortcoming as `fgets`: buf is indeterminate upon read error or overlong input.  I think it would be better to set `*buf = '\0';` in this case, provided `size > 0`.  `fgets` leaves the buffer untouched upon EOF, but this specified behavior is more error prone than useful.

Comment: @chqrlie Agree.  The "Ha!" was to indicate the my disagreement that such a line of reasoning, though hopeful in 1999, did not play out by 2011.

Comment: @chqrlie Agree to your idea.  A pedantic solution would dig deeper into `ferror()` and `feof()` for when `fgets()` returns `NULL`.  With `fgets()`, the buffer is left alone on `feof()`, yet indeterminate on `ferror()`.  I suspect `gets()` worked the same.  So `*buf = '\0'` may make sense on `ferror()` only.

Comment: @chqrlie In the 2nd case I was using the invisible swap(lines-of-code) routine.  Fixed now.