# Read and print the string in C

Tags: c

So I have been trying to read input string and then print it by not using neither `scanf()` nor `printf()` but `getchar()` and `putchar()` instead.
It seems like the program is stuck in the loop, I'm not able to spot an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getstring(char *c)
{
char inS[100];
char n;
int i = 0;  
while ((n = getchar()) != '\n') {
    inS[i] = n;
    i++;        
}
inS[i] = '\0';
i = 0;
while (inS[i] != '\0') {
    putchar(inS[i]);
    i++;
}
}
main()
{
char *prompt;
prompt = "Enter a sentence: \n";
getstring(&prompt);
printf("%s", prompt);

}
```

Comment: Step 1: `getstring(&prompt);` --> `getstring(prompt);`  (drop &)`

Comment: What does `getstring(char *c)` do with `c`?  Is posted code the true code you are running?

Comment: `getstring()` is a function that I created to read input string using `getchar()` and then print it using `putchar()`

Comment: Yes I see `getstring() is a function`.  What does code do with `c`?  Does the code posted match the code you are running?

Comment: Yes it is exactly the code which I'm running

Comment: `getstring(char *c)` appears to do nothing with `c`.  Is that code's intent?

Comment: What are the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: it should be `Enter your sentence:` `abc` `abc`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between int and char in getchar() and putchar()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-and-putchar)

Comment: Did you remember to compile with all warnings enabled? `-Wall -Werror`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some problems. Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getstring(void) /* You don't use the passed argument. So, I've removed it */
{
    char inS[100];
    /* `char n;` getchar() returns an int, not a char */
    int n;
    int i = 0;  
    while (i < 99 && (n = getchar()) != '\n' && n != EOF)  /* Added condition for preventing a buffer overrun and also for EOF */
    {
        inS[i] = n;
        i++;        
    }
    inS[i] = '\0';
    putchar('\n'); /* For seperating input and output in the console */
    i = 0;
    while (inS[i] != '\0')
    {
        putchar(inS[i]);
        i++;
    }
    putchar('\n'); /* For cleanliness and flushing of stdout */
}
int main(void) /* Standard signature of main */
{
    char *prompt;
    prompt = "Enter a sentence: \n";
    printf("%s", prompt); /* Interchanged these two lines */
    getstring(); /* Nothing to pass to the function */
    return 0; /* End main with a return code of 0 */
}
```

Note: The loop for input will end when either

- A `\n`(<kbd>Enter</kbd>) has been encountered.
- An `EOF` has been encountered.
- 99 characters were read from `stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not adding \n in your stdin? Executing your code was successful. Also you are not modifying passed `char *c`, why? And to modify a pointer you should pass a pointer to a pointer ([How do I modify a pointer that has been passed into a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c))

Comment: I changed it to `getstring(char** c)` but it still didn't help

Comment: Because your are not modifying c pointer. Again, loop problem is only because there is no \n at the end of your string.

Answer (score 0):

First you can make all the elements of the array to NULL.

```
 char inS[100] = {"\0",};
```

You can use gets() to get the string from the console. some thing as below.

your code

```
while ((n = getchar()) != '\n') {
    inS[i] = n;
    i++;        
}
```

Modify it as:

```
gets(inS);
```

Then you can do the other operation what ever you want.

Comment: `gets()` is no longer part of the standard C library for the past 5 years.

Comment: @chux, Sorry to say you, but that exists. After your comment I checked and verified using gets(). Which is working absolutely fine. for your info, Please check the any kernel source code those are implemented in C, widely uses gets().

Comment: C11 removed `gets()`.  "removed the `gets` function (`<stdio.h>`)".  Perhaps you are working with a non up-to-date compiler or codebase?

Comment: @chux Why do you assumes it would be C11. Any way the question was not tagged with C11.

Comment: My comments made no assumption about the code being C11, C99 or earlier.  Simple pointed out "gets() is no longer part of the standard C library for the past 5 years"  which is when C11 was made the standard.

Comment: I sorry to say. I think you can go through windows or linux kernel source code for a batter understanding. These people are still using them. Any way it is again on to you how and what you want to use :)

Comment: [simple replacement for gets()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031129/since-the-standard-c-committee-did-not-standardize-a-simple-replacement-for-gets) addresses the replacement issue.  Since it is not available with current C compliers, new source code should not use it.

Answer (score 0):

getchar replaces \n character with \0 whenever it sees a newline character. So n will never be \n.
You should try getc or fgetc.

Comment: I think you are on to it.  With buffered data, text is waiting for a flush or  `'\n'`.

Comment: So that `while` condition will always be true? hence the infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing a new line. After `putchar(ch)` you should use `putchar('\n')` to print a new line

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void getstring(char *c)
{
char n;
int i = 0;
while ((n = getchar()) != '\n')
{
 *c=n;
  c++;
}
c = '\0';
main()
{
char inS[100];
char *prompt=inS;
getstring(prompt);
printf("%s", prompt);
}
```

**strong text**

In main() function only pointer is declared but it is not assigned to any symbol in other words pointer declared but it does not refer to any memory location. That problem is solved in this solution

Comment: Add those description to answer, not in comment, So that OP will find it helpful. That's not for me,. I was from review